# I can't add items to either ComboBox or ChoiceBox when adding another stage

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

So, I have two .fxml files, the other one working as main and the other one as basically window that pops up.

```
@FXML private void handleSelection() throws Error {            
        try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("StudentChoose.fxml"));
                Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
                stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
      sBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("New Document", "Open ", "Save", "Save as"));
}
```

This is what I have. I have stated the sBox above with
@FXML private ChoiceBox sBox;

Everything works PERFECTLY when the choicebox/combobox is on the main stage, but when it is on the other stage - it doesn't. I have a .fxml file for this another stage with the content, id is set as 'sBox' for the choicebox - but it doesn't work. Instead it returns me a java.lang.NullPointerException on the line where I call to add items to it. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same class for both controllers?

Comment: So you have 2 FXML files and one controller for one of them.
Why should it work? sBox here is a reference to a member of the controller (the class that you have copied) injected by the loader.
You shall have another controller for your second FXML file, with a public function to manipulate the list of the combobox there (e.g. a public property of ObservableList of Strings or simply a public method "setComboBoxList"). Then here fxmlloader.getController().setComboBoxList("A", "B", "C").

I hope I understood it well.

Comment: Or just initialize the choice box in the second controller's `initialize()` method...